# How to know what the outcome of indexOf("character", integer) will be?

Tags: java, char, indexof

I don't understand why `name.indexOf("d",4)` prints 8, in my program. I try replacing other letters for "d" but it always seems to print a random number, and I don't see any pattern to understand what the `indexOf("character", integer)` is actually doing, and how it comes up with its output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    name = "abcdefghd";

    System.out.println(name.indexOf("d"));//3
    System.out.println(name.indexOf("cde"));//2
    System.out.println(name.indexOf("fe"));//-1
    System.out.println(name.indexOf("d", 4));//8
}
```

Comment: Have you read its javadoc?

Comment: Hint: `8` is the index of the first occurrence of "d" after index '4'.  Does that get you started?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered by a simple look at the standard documentation.

Comment: Are "easy" and "off-topic" the same thing?

Comment: You should read javadocs before asking others for help.

Comment: For god's sake, don't try to guess what a method does. **You can't throw a dead cat not to hit the Java API doc with the proper explanations...**

Comment: @pamphlet - No, easy and off-topic are not the same thing. This question should not be closed.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm    I read this, it did not have the answer I was looking for. Geez, sorry for wasting your precious time.

Comment: Although considered easy from the perspective of a seasoned professional, this is a well-written question with a nice, concise code example demonstrating the problem. Voting to reopen this post.

Comment: Reopen voters, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3251/closing-easy-questions-yes-or-no for more details.

Comment: From your link; "public int indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex): Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character, starting the search at the specified index or -1 if the character does not occur." Regardless, docs are often the way forward

Comment: @jmort253 It has an answer, so it doesn't need to be reopened.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - That logic doesn't make much sense. Closed doesn't mean answered. Closed means, in this case, off-topic, which it's not.

Comment: @jmort253 the asker did little to no research on this, and the offical java docs are a better place to look for the answer. Otherwise, I'm going to start making a million "What is sum(x,y) doing in language Z? - I change the numbers and the output is always different?"

Answer (score 4):

The [`String#indexOf(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method looks for the specified `String` at an index at or after the specified `int`.

So

```
System.out.println(name.indexOf("d", 4));//8
```

in

```
name = "abcdefghd";
            ^ index 4
```

It starts looking for the `"d"` at index 4 in the `String`, ie. after the `"d"` at index 3. There's a `"d"` in index 8.

Answer (score 3):

The returned value is not random, it's explained right here in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring, starting at the specified index.
>
> The returned index is the smallest value k for which `k >= fromIndex && this.startsWith(str, k)`. If no such value of k exists, then -1 is returned.

Just in case: remember that in Java indexes start at `0`.